Does changing Salesforce callback url for a app invalidates the current Access or Refresh tokens?
Suppose I am changing the Callback URL of the salesforce app, will it invalidate the access and refresh token of the salesforce app which were generated via the previous callback URL?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you change the callback URL in the app, that does not automatically invalidate existing access or refresh tokens. It can affect the OAuth flow for future token requests. If the callback URL is incorrect or not updated properly, new tokens might not be issued correctly. If you need to ensure that all tokens are invalidated, you would have to manually revoke them or rotate the consumer key and secret.
For more information, you can refer these articles:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.perm_uapa_update_callback_URL.htm&type=5
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_create_api_integration.htm&type=5

